# SQL: How to build complex query from 3 tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables with data and I need to select sum of sales (SalesAmount) per country(CountryRegionName) in 2014 fiscal year (FiscalYear).

The first table is `Geography`.

There are data with `CountryRegionName` and also `SalesTerritoryKey` (number which means some districts of `CountryRegionName`).

The second table, anong others, has information about `OrderDateKey`, `SalesTerritoryKey` and `SalesAmount`. The `OrderDateKey` field include records in the following format: "20130828".

The third table, among others, has fields `DateKey` (in the same format as `OrderDateKey` from second table and `FiscalYear` (format like: "2012").

I dont't understand how I can select needed data using all 3 tables because second table has information about year (`OrderDateKey`) in different format which third table supports in field `FiscalYear`.

Currently I stopped which following statement:

```
`SELECT CountryRegionName, SUM(SalesAmount) FROM FirstTable  GROUP BY SalesTerritoryKey`
```

I know that we need to join all tables and make some subqueries but don't understand how to compare dates and countries which are in different formats.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Don't describe the tables. Paste the code to create the tables and populate sample data.

Comment: Or at the very least post a formatted table in your question that demonstrates it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT t1.CountryRegionName, SUM(t2.SalesAmount) 
FROM ThirdTable  t3
LEFT JOIN SecondTable t2
ON t3.DateKey = t2.OrderDateKey
LEFT JOIN FirstTable t1
ON t1.SalesTerritoryKey = t2.SalesTerritoryKey
WHERE t3.FiscalYear = "2014"
GROUP BY t1.CountryRegionName
```

Comment: Why do you use LEFT JOIN but not INNER JOIN?

Comment: because if you have 2014 fiscal year in table3 but have no data in others you will still get empty result. but if you set inner join - you'll get no result

Comment: I think that this query will firstly join all data, and only after that filter by FiscalYear, so there wouldn't be that problem?

Comment: why do you think that way?

Comment: Can you advise me some resources where I can learn how to create such complex quiries? I am pretty new to SQL and only can to write elementary queries but it is hard to me to make combined queries.

Comment: stackoverflow is the best place. but just google through before you start asking :-) it is just time you nedd, query by query you will get it! :-)